# Facebook Deep Linking not working in Android

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

Anyone have any idea why I am getting Deferred Deep linking issue. please check below screen[image]shot.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add below line of code in onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    Uri targetUrl =
      AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
    if (targetUrl != null) {
        Log.i("Activity", "App Link Target URL: " + targetUrl.toString());
    } else {
        AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(
            activity, 
            new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                    //process applink data
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android

Comment: Thanks Vidhi. So In this case, I have to create Deeplink Right ?

Comment: Yes. For that you can define that in your manifest file inside <intent-filter> tag. example: <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.domain.com" />